# Convex optimization with Ridge regression

Tags: convex-optimization, regression, karush-kuhn-tucker, lagrange-interpolation

If this is the constrained version of ridge regression:

min
w∈Rd
∥Φw − y∥^2
s.t. ∥w∥2 ≤ s,
(1)

where Φ ∈ R
n×d and y ∈ R
n
. Answer the following questions.

•How can we prove that this is a convex optimization problem.

•Does strong duality really hold? If yes, derive the KKT condition regarding the optimal
solution w∗ for the above problem.

• Does a closed-form solution exist? If yes, derive the closed-form
solution. If not, can you propose an algorithm for computing the optimal solution (describe the
key steps of your algorithm)?
Please Help

Comment: You need to show some work.

Comment: I differentiated it twice and got it >0. Is it enough to prove it as convex. And I don't know how to prove it as strong duality

Comment: ||Φw − y∥^2 +lambda(∥w∥2-s) on differentiating it twice

Comment: 2λI+2XtransposeX, which is always positive as λ>=0